# can we add fingerprint from my app programmatically

Tags: android, security, authentication, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I have search lot on internet/stackoveflow how to add fingerprint from custom app but couldn't found any clue

In short **Requirement -** I am creating app that will allow user to enter into my app by scanning fingerprint.

I have check code that will scan finger on sensor and return fingerprint data already set by user (He/She set from setting) but in case if there are multiple finger set by multiple user than my app allow all the user to enter into my app which i don't want

**What I want -** Code that add fingerprint from my app and allow only that user not all the user to enter into my app

Now some question -

1. is it possible to do this?
2. is there any other way to archive this
3. is this secure way to do so because my application is banking
   related

Comment: Not a definite answer but look at this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.java#258

Comment: did you understand my question vijai coz i am confused that is this is right way to ask user to set finger from my app or send him to setting screen to set fingerprint

Comment: Well, it was added in comment for a reason. Android treats every fingerprint equally and does not recommend identifying individual fingerprints. You can neither register fingerprint from within your app nor save the fingerprint privately for your app only. Android manages them with their own keychain. You must direct user to settings screen using intent for registering fingerprint and identify user somehow using something like above link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but in case if there are multiple finger set by multiple user than my app allow all the user to enter into my app which i don't want

You have no way of distinguishing between "multiple finger set by multiple user" and "multiple finger set by one user". Most people have more than one finger.

> Code that add fingerprint from my app and allow only that user not all the user to enter into my app

You can require that the person holding the device scan their fingerprint and have that be authenticated against registered fingerprints. You have no way of knowing who the person is who scanned their fingerprint and their relationship with the owner of the device. It might *be* the owner, or it might not. That is up to the device owner, not you.

This is no different than most other forms of authentication. For example, if your app required a custom PIN, and the user shared that PIN with somebody else, *that is the user's choice*. It may be a stupid choice, or it may not (e.g., it is shared with a spouse).

Comment: as per scenario it is not possible to identify that unique user is there any other way we can achieve this functionality ?(security is important)

Comment: @sushantgosavi: You have no good way of doing that in the real world (e.g., distinguishing identical twins), let alone from an app.

Comment: Okay leave finger prints registered with device settings,is it possible to ad a new fingerprint from our app or should be navigate to settings?

Comment: @Ramprasad: One way or another, the user winds up in Settings. With `BiometricPrompt` on Android P, it seems to launch the enroll-a-fingerprint screens automatically if the user has not set up a fingerprint yet. I have not tried that scenario with `FingerprintManager`, though.